# drag&drop not working in Opera 11.62 and Safari 5.1.4

Tags: html, safari, drag-and-drop, opera

I put this code in a test HTML file:

```
<head>
<script>
f=function() {
el=document.getElementById('dragdiv');
el.ondragover=function(){return false;};
el.ondragenter=function(){return false;};
el.ondrop=function(event){ 
el.innerHTML=event.dataTransfer.getData('Text');};
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='f()'>
<div id='dragdiv'>DROP HERE ------------------------</div>
<img src='image.jpg'></img>
```

(Tags were removed)
It works in Chrome but not in Opera and Safari because the mouse cursor does not change into an arrow like in Chrome. What is wrong with this code in Opera and Safari?

Comment: Can you please create an example page? Preferably http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Styxxy http://jsfiddle.net/sX2u2/

Comment: You are aware that the drag/drop functionality doesn't work yet in Opera 11.xx? Normally it should be available in Opera 12 (you can test it in the beta).

Comment: @Styxxy I was not aware of it, and what about Safari?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use it. You can try some online HTML5 drag & drop demos to see whether it works or not. What I saw on Google (just a 2 second look) is that there are many people with D&D problems in Safari 5.1.x .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag and drop support is coming in Opera 12, which is now out in beta. As far as I can tell, it works in the beta release.